# Wireless, battery operated web cam for mobile robot

Tags: arduino, video, netduino, mobile-robot

I'm working on a Netduino based mobile robot that's controlled by software on a PC or phone (WP7).  One goal of the project is to be able to steer the robot from another room of the house.  Is there a small wireless (wifi) web cam that runs on battery that may work for this situation?  I don't think the Netduino has enough processing power to stream video, though technially it could using a wifi shield.  If that's out of the question would it be possible to sporatically take pictures using some other camera sensor & the Netduino (photos could be stored on the SD card and later served up over wifi to the client)?

Comment: How is your project going now? I have drawn up a similar plan with arduino and its ethernet shield. I have referred to related articles on website and gotten the same conclusion as mjcarroll(#3) about also arduino. So I have my plan completed as a car(*1) with arduino and a IP-camera on the market(*2). (*1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrEwOXd1hUU (*2) http://www.iodata.jp/product/mobile/lancam/ts-wptcam/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that the Netduino has the processing power that you want to stream video over the network.  I believe that you could get any wifi webcam to work with the robot, though.  You would just need a little extra space in your power budget to account for the camera's additional power usage.

Depending on how soon you need the camera, I would just watch the winter sales on any of the big technology suppliers (Newegg, Tigerdirect, Amazon) for a deal on a wifi webcam that meets the specifications that you are looking for.

If you are looking to make your project entirely self-contained, then you may want to check out the [CMUcam](http://www.cmucam.org/).  It provides a good vision sensor, without having to do much processing on your Netduino chip.  It can do most basic vision processing on-board, without the need for your chip to handle the processor intensive image processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use your phone as a camera as well as the controller.

This is what I am planning to do in the near future with an Android phone and Arduino BT (or Arduino + Bluetooth chip) connecting the to devices via Bluetooth.